# PHP Parser and converter - SOLID and DRY

Tags: php, parsing, csv, converting, strategy-pattern

I am working on a PHP application that transforms data from the input CSV (JSON, TXT, or XML) into an output CSV (JSON or database, for example).

The output format differs from the input: some columns can be skipped, and some values can be converted (e.g. blue => 1, or 1.85 => 185). Also, the headers can have different names in the output file.

The parser can read the input file, the converter performs the transformations, and then the storage service writes files or inserts a record in the database.

I want to follow SOLID and DRY principles, and my software should be open for ongoing extension but closed to edits and modification.

I created a command (Symfony command), and here is the execute method:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        if (!$this->lock()) {
            $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');

            return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        // Get the fileInputPath argument and check if the file exists
        $fileInputPath = $input->getArgument('fileInputPath');

        $filesystem = new Filesystem();
        if (!$filesystem->exists($fileInputPath)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException('File not found.');
        }

        // Get the fileInputPath extension and instantiate the right parser
        $fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($fileInputPath);
        $fileExt = $fileInfo->getExtension();

        $parser = sprintf('\\App\\Parsers\\%sParser', strtoupper($fileExt));
        $parserContext = new ParserContext(new $parser());
        $rows = $parserContext->parseData($fileInputPath);

        // For which customer do you want to import new data?
        $customer = $input->getOption('customer');

        $headersConverter = sprintf('\\App\\Converters\\%s\\HeadersConverter', $customer);
        $converterService = sprintf('\\App\\Services\\%s\\ConverterService', $customer);

        // Data conversion
        $columnsToSkip = [];
        $convertedRows = [];
        foreach ($rows as $x => $row) {
            $yy = 0; // Since I can skip some columns (e.g. Name), I need a new index to identify the columns
            foreach ($row as $y => $column) {
                if ($x === 0) { // convert headers
                    $convertedHeader = $headersConverter::convert($column);
                    if ($convertedHeader) {
                        $convertedRows[0][] = $convertedHeader;
                    } else {
                        $columnsToSkip[] = $y; // Skip columns that do not have a header conversion
                    }
                } else { // convert values
                    $currentColumn = null;
                    if (array_key_exists($yy, $convertedRows[0])) {
                        $currentColumn = $convertedRows[0][$yy];
                    }

                    if (!in_array($y, $columnsToSkip)) {
                        $convertedRows[$x][$y] = $converterService::convert($currentColumn, $column);
                        $yy++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Write on file or database
        $storageType = $input->getArgument('storageType');
        $fileOutputPath = $input->getArgument('fileOutputPath');

        $storage = StorageService::getStorageObjectFromStorageType($storageType, $fileOutputPath);

        $storageContext = new StorageContext($storage);
        $storageContext->saveData($convertedRows);

        // Print output
        $output->writeln([
            'Command run successfully!',
        ]);

        if (in_array($storageType, ['csv', 'json'])) {
            $output->writeln([
                sprintf('A new %s file has been created in the data folder.', $storageType)
            ]);
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

Based on the input file extension, the following line can decide which parser to use:

```
$parser = sprintf('\\App\\Parsers\\%sParser', strtoupper($fileExt));
```

Depending on the name of the customer (an option of the command), I can convert headers and values with different classes:

```
$headersConverter = sprintf('\\App\\Converters\\%s\\HeadersConverter', $customer);
$converterService = sprintf('\\App\\Services\\%s\\ConverterService', $customer);
```

I rely on static methods. Maybe there is a better way to do it. Can you suggest me something, please?
Also, the execute method is very procedurally written and may contain too much logic.

Any review is very welcome. If you need more code, I am happy to share it with you.

Comment: This function is starting to get Too Long. Maybe that `foreach` loop is a good candidate for your first Extract Helper ?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree, I moved it into its RowsConverter class. This is now that part:   $convertedRows = (new RowsConverter(new $headersConverter(), new $converterService()))
            ->convert($rows);

Answer (score 4):

## Design patterns

#### 1. Use Dependency Injection

Use dependency injection instead of creating parsers and converters in the `execute` method. This makes your code easier to test. You can set up your parsers and converters as services and inject them into your command. This will require configuring your services for different implementations based on the file extension or customer name.

##### Example for Service Configuration:

You can configure your services dynamically with tags or a factory pattern, choosing the right service based on input.

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
  App\Parsers\CsvParser:
    tags:
      - { name: 'app.parser', format: 'csv' }

  App\Converters\Default\HeadersConverter:
    tags:
      - { name: 'app.converter', customer: 'default' }
```

Then, dynamically inject the service container or tagged services to select the right one.

#### 2. Abstract Factory Pattern

Consider using an Abstract Factory pattern to create parsers and converters based on file type (or customer). This will separate the creation and main logic, making it easier to manage.

##### Factory Example:

Create factory classes for parsers and converters that use an identifier (file extension or customer name) to give back the right instance.

```
namespace App\Factory;

class ParserFactory
{
    public static function create(string $fileExt)
    {
        switch (strtoupper($fileExt)) {
            case 'CSV':
                return new CsvParser();
            // More cases as needed
            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported file extension: $fileExt");
        }
    }
}
```

Use factories in the command to get parsers and converters.

#### 3. Simplify `execute` Logic

The `execute` method does a lot: it locks the process, parses, converts and saves data. Try breaking it into smaller methods or moving some logic to dedicated services for better clarity and testing.

##### Refactoring Example:

```
final protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    if (!$this->lock()) {
        $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');
        return Command::FAILURE;
    }

    $fileInputPath = $input->getArgument('fileInputPath');
    $this->validateFileExists($fileInputPath);

    $rows = $this->parseData($fileInputPath, $input);
    $convertedRows = $this->convertData($rows, $input);

    $this->saveData($convertedRows, $input, $output);

    $output->writeln('Command run successfully!');
    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
```

#### 4. Use Interfaces

Use interfaces for parsers and converters to keep them consistent and interchangeable (`ParserInterface`, `ConverterInterface`).

## Implementing SOLID

Let's make some modifications that will show examples of each SOLID principle.

#### Single Responsibility Principle

Divide command into smaller, focused classes, each with a single responsibility.

##### Refactoring Example:

```
// Handles file parsing
class FileParser {
    public function parse(string $filePath): array {
        // File parsing logic
    }
}

// Handles data conversion
class DataConverter {
    public function convert(array $data): array {
        // Data conversion logic
    }
}

// Handles data saving
class DataStorage {
    public function save(array $data): void {
        // Data saving logic
    }
}

// `YourCommand` orchestrates the workflow, relying on the specialized classes
class YourCommand extends Command {
    private $fileParser;
    private $dataConverter;
    private $dataStorage;

    public function __construct(FileParser $fileParser, DataConverter $dataConverter, DataStorage $dataStorage) {
        $this->fileParser = $fileParser;
        $this->dataConverter = $dataConverter;
        $this->dataStorage = $dataStorage;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // The execute method leverages these dedicated services
}
```

#### Open/Closed Principle

The command directly creates parser and converter instances, requiring modifications to add new formats.

**Solution:** Polymorphism and dependency injection will allow extension without modification of the existing code.

##### OCP Refactoring Example:

```
interface ParserInterface {
    public function parse(string $filePath): array;
}

interface ConverterInterface {
    public function convert(array $data): array;
}

class CsvParser implements ParserInterface {
    public function parse(string $filePath): array {
        // CSV parsing logic
    }
}

class JsonParser implements ParserInterface {
    public function parse(string $filePath): array {
        // JSON parsing logic
    }
}

// Symfony DI container can be configured to inject the correct parser based on the application's needs
```

#### Liskov Substitution Principle, Interface Segregation Principle, and Dependency Inversion Principle

These principles aim to create robust, interchangeable interfaces and promote abstraction over concrete implementations.

**Current Issue**: `YourCommand` is closely tied to specific parsing, converting, and data storage implementations.

**Proposed Solution**:
Define clear interfaces for each task and make sure that any subclass or implementation can be substituted without affecting functionality.

##### Refactoring for LSP, ISP, and DIP:

````
// Given the interfaces above, ensure all concrete implementations are fully interchangeable.

class YourCommand extends Command {
    // Accept interfaces in the constructor, allowing for any conforming implementation
    public function __construct(ParserInterface $parser, ConverterInterface $converter, DataStorageInterface $dataStorage) {
        // Class setup
    }

    // The class operates the same but is now decoupled from specific implementations
}
```
````